# Cannot return null in JavaFX dialog result converter

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, javafx-8

I have three different buttons on my dialog pane, i.e., `dialogPane.saveButton`, `dialogPane.deleteButton` and `dialogPane.cancelButton`.

Depending on which button has been pressed, I want to return different things (especially, I want to return null if the delete button was pressed):

```
setResultConverter(result -> {
  if (result == dialogPane.saveButton) {
    return new Data("Save button has been pressed");
  } else if (result == dialogPane.deleteButton) {
    return null;
  }
  return defaultData;
});
```

Yet, above implementation is not correct, or at least, it does not do what I expect it to do.
Using the debugger, I can see that when the delete button is clicked, null gets returned correctly (called from [`Dialog#impl_setResultAndClose`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/1.0.1/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.java#Dialog.impl_setResultAndClose%28javafx.scene.control.ButtonType%2Cboolean%29)). Yet, after that, the result converter is called again, this time with a fallback to the cancel button for some reason.

I read the [dialog documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) over and over again, but I cannot make sense of it. It states

> Dialog Closing Rules
>
> It is important to understand what happens when a Dialog is closed, and also how a Dialog can be closed, especially in abnormal closing situations (such as when the 'X' button is clicked in a dialogs title bar, or when operating system specific keyboard shortcuts (such as alt-F4 on Windows) are entered). Fortunately, the outcome is well-defined in these situations, and can be best summarised in the following bullet points:
>
> - JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in two situations:
>
>   - When the dialog only has one button, or
>   - When the dialog has multiple buttons, as long as one of them meets one of the following requirements:
>
>     - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData is of type ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.
>     - The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData returns true when ButtonBar.ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called.
> - In all other situations, the dialog will refuse to respond to all close requests, remaining open until the user clicks on one of the available buttons in the DialogPane area of the dialog.
> - If a dialog is closed abnormally, and if the dialog contains a button which meets one of the two criteria above, the dialog will attempt to set the result property to whatever value is returned from calling the result converter with the first matching ButtonType.
> - If for any reason the result converter returns null, or if the dialog is closed when only one non-cancel button is present, the result property will be null, and the showAndWait() method will return Optional.empty(). This later point means that, if you use either of option 2 or option 3 (as presented earlier in this class documentation), the Optional.ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer) lambda will never be called, and code will continue executing as if the dialog had not returned any value at all.

In my understanding, I meet the last point: My dialog does not close abnormally (it is closed via a click on the button) and my result converter returns null, so I expect it to return `Optional.empty()`. Yet, it tries to return the value returned by the cancel button (the bullet above the last point).

Am I misunderstanding something here (e.g., do I wrongly interpret the word abnormally?), or is there an implementation mistake in JavaFX's dialog system?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit weird. If you set the `ButtonData` of your "Delete" button to `CANCEL_CLOSE`, it will at least call the converter a second time with the "Delete" button, instead of the "Cancel" button, so it returns `Optional.empty()` as expected (at least in my test: you may need to provide a [MCVE]). Not sure why it is calling the converter twice at all, though.

Comment: @James_D: Oh yeah, you are right, setting the delete button's type to `CANCEL_CLOSE` could solve this problem. Thanks for the advice! But I am kinda glad to see someone else also being not sure about the twice-calling behavior.

Comment: It does look like somewhere the dialog implementation is assuming that a null value from the converter indicates an "abnormal" close of the dialog, where, as you point out, that shouldn't be the case. Have you tested this on the latest JDK?

Comment: @James_D No, I am still running Java 8 (openjdk version "1.8.0_151" with javafx (openjfx) runtime version 8.0.60) but I could test it with the latest Java 9 tomorrow.